# Can you splice USB cables?

Tags: usb, cable

**tl;dr:** can I expect to still be able to form a USB connection to my computer after splicing a USB cable?

---

I have a USB game controller ([Logitech F310](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/products/gamepads/f310-gamepad.940-000110.html) if it matters) and my son keeps pulling or tripping on the cord. I am concerned for him and the controller. I've been thinking about splicing the USB cord with a magnetic release like original XBox controller or the MacBooks have.

However, I am concerned that if I add solder to the wires or the magnetic field itself might make the controller unable to connect to computer due to signal degradation.

So, can I expect to still be able to form a USB connection to my computer after splicing a USB cable?

---

PS- In case it matters I was thinking of using a "magnetic USB charging data cable" from Amazon to splice in for the mag-release

Comment: It was a toss up between posting here on and on the [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) stack exchange, but this is more popular and it still seems [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Any USB cable that I have seen (broken and dismantled) is made with very fine wires and interspersed threads to enhance durability when flexed. They are not readily repaired.

Comment: Definitely not on-topic on Electrical Engineering SE (I'm an active user there). John is correct. I would recommend a USB extension cable.

Comment: Why would the author make the cable longer?  It sounds like the length of the cable is already long enough and is half the issue.

Comment: I personally wouldn't go this route but I have indeed spliced USB cables when working on embedded devices with custom connectors.  I have had MIXED results as I can't stop shaking from all of the caffeine in my system.  Theoretically possible.. and yet probably not the best use of your time.

Comment: 1. If you are familiar with soldering microelectronics (or at least *very* fine wires), USB cables certainly can be spliced. Use a hot wire-stripper to avoid damaging fine wires. 2. A spliced cable has impedance discontinuities, which may cause minor signal reflections or limit bandwidth. For a controller, this should not be an issue.